# WebApi2 Controller using Json.NET failing to deserialize single property

Tags: c#, .net, post, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

When sending a POST request with a confirmed well formed object to a WebApi2 controller which is using Json.NET for deserialization, a single property is not correctly parsed.

The JSON sent out in the request is as follows:

```
{"ParentId":8,"Data":{"Description":"Estimated Man Hours ONSITE","ExternalItemKey":"Services:Man Hours","Quantity":0,"Price":150,"EstimatedCost":60},"ActualCost":60,"DateProvided":"2015-09-18T00:26:45.000Z","ReferencedQuotedDeliverableExternalGuid":"1b7e42be-670e-4d84-9600-15dff530363e","Notes":""}
```

The Data.EstimatedCost value deserializes as 0, likely as it is not being parsed for some reason. All other values are parsed properly.

The version of Json.NET is 6.0.0.0

Comment: In your JSON, the `ActualCost` property is not part of the `data` object; it is part of the containing object.  (`EstimatedCost`, on the other hand, *is* part of the data object.)  You don't show your classes in your question, but I suspect that is your real problem.  Many times it can help if you use a JSON validator like [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) to reformat the JSON.  It becomes much more obvious what properties belong to what objects that way.

Comment: That was a typo on my part. It should have read "The Data.Estimated Cost value..." Thanks for pointing it out!

The problem was that the JSON.NET deserializer in version 6.0.0.0 has a bug in it. I provided this Q/A largely to provide a work-around for others who encounter the same issue. Chances are the bug is fixed in a later version, but if you don't have the time/means to swap out the library, then the workaround is useful.

Comment: I see; thanks for updating your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which I found for this was to mark the variable which is failing to deserialize as required with the following syntax:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Deliverable
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public decimal EstimatedCost { get; private set; }
}
```